# What if a statement is vocalized as a question?

Tags: halacha, speech-talking

When making a statement or declaration, such as "i'm making a *kinyan* for *Ploni*", must it be vocalized as a statement, or can it sound like a question (raising the tone at the end a little; hopefully you know what i mean). This is assuming we're not discussing [someone who always talks like that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valleyspeak).

In other words, must it be recognizable as a statement, or must you merely say the words?

Edit: I'm referring to any kind of statement that changes something's status in Halacha. Some examples: making a kinyan, taking challah, taking trumot and maasrot, etc.

Comment: "Unclear what you're asking" -- what *halachos* are impacted by this question?

Comment: As i said, making a kinyan, for example. Taking challah is also a statement.

Comment: I don't know for certain, but I could definitely imagine that there are different requirements for *kinyan* and *challah*....you might want to clarify exactly what your question is.

Comment: I asked this question to Rabbi Asher Arieli several years ago and he smiled, but didn't have an answer.

Comment: @Shokhet Any better now?

Comment: Are there formal verbal-only *kinyanim*? The *kinyanim* I'm aware of whose form are defined in *Halacha* tend to require a particular action.

Comment: Yes, much clearer....though I'm still not sure that all verbal statements have the same rules.....also, *terumah* works with a thought (see, e.g., [Gittin 31a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=19&daf=31&format=pdf) [top])

Comment: http://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/27zefp/whats_the_worst_thing_you_could_add_a_question/ci5v32y